# How to check file size upon upload?

Tags: image, file-upload, liferay, velocity, web-content

I am using Liferays asset publisher and trying to configure the web content to handle images and documents. The document upload can be handled by the document library that liferay has to offer but when images have no such place. The template for the web content is written in velocity. Is there a way within velocity to check file extensions and size when uploaded? Or if there are any other ways this could be handled?

I just got done messing around with Liferay 6.1 Beta3, it is still buggy but not as bad as the trunks. The asset publisher has some improved features which include the document library having a folder structure. I think this is the way I am going to go, is just have any file used within the web content must be pushed through the document library. Also unrelated to the question the web content now has the feature to localize both the title and the abstract. Hopefully they get all the bugs fixed by release time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Control Panel -> Server Administration -> File Uploads

In that you can specify the Overall Maximum File Size ,Maximum File Size and allowed extensions  for Document Library,Maximum File Size and allowed extensions for Images and Maximum File Size and allowed extensions for Web content images.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @sandeepnair85, but the custom structures and templates for the web content are not tied into liferays management. I wish that was the case. I didn't know if there was a way for velocity to check, then bypass if not the correct file type or size.